# Not getting BLE client connection notifications using Tmds.Dbus library

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

Environment: Ubuntu 20.04

I am running a BlueZ BLE gatt server and need to know when a client connects.

I have a simple program to monitor BlueZ device connections that is based on Tmds.Dbus (https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.DBus). Here is the relevant code:

```
   using(var connection = new Connection(Address.System)) {
     connection.StateChanged += (s, e) => OnStateChanged(e);
     await connection.ConnectAsync();
     var dev = connection.CreateProxy<bluez.DBus.IDevice1>("org.bluez", "/org/bluez/hci0");
     await dev.WatchPropertiesAsync(p => {
         Console.WriteLine("Property");
     });
     var objManager = connection.CreateProxy<bluez.DBus.IObjectManager>("org.bluez", "/org/bluez/hci0");
     await objManager.WatchInterfacesAddedAsync(obj => {
        Console.WriteLine("Added");
     });
     ...

    [DBusInterface("org.bluez.Device1")]
    interface IDevice1 : IDBusObject
    {
        ...
        Task<IDisposable> WatchPropertiesAsync(Action<PropertyChanges> handler);
    }

    [DBusInterface("org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager")]
    interface IObjectManager : IDBusObject
    {
        Task<IDisposable> WatchInterfacesAddedAsync(Action<(ObjectPath @object, IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, object>> interfaces)> handler, Action<Exception> onError = null);
        ...
    }
```

The problem I am running into is that I never get any event at all when a client connects or disconnects. However, if I run dbus-monitor, I can see InterfacesAdded on ObjectManager and Property changes on Device1.

Wondering if I am just missing something. Tmds.Dbus is just a .NET core wrapper over DBus APIs. Regards

Comment: I don't know C# so could be wrong but the `using` statement with your DBus connection looks like a red flag. You're telling the connection to notify you on property changes but after that I guess the connection gets dropped immediately... Make sure the connection object exists as long as you are insterested in the notifications

Comment: Thanks Jussi. The connection does stay open.